# Listen to a folder and modify incoming files on change

Tags: shell-script, fork, tshark, pcap

I want to convert pcap files to json files using shell script (and tshark). As soon as one or more new pcap files are copied into a folder, the command tshark should be executed and the resulting json data should be stored in another file (in a different order). As soon as the conversion is finished the pacap file should be deleted.

The idea looks something like that:

```
while(true){
   wait_for_IN_folder_changed
   tshark -T ek -x -r \in\in.pcap > \out\out.json
   rm \in\in.pcap
}
```

It would be best to start the tshark process multithreaded to increase the parallelism and thus the throughput. But would different threads probably get in each other's way here?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-dir-processor

> **EXAMPLE: GNU Parallel as dir processor**
>
> If you have a dir in which users drop files that needs to be processed you can do this on GNU/Linux (If you know what inotifywait is called on other platforms file a bug report):
>
> ```
> inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir |\
>   parallel -u echo
> ```
>
> This will run the command echo on each file put into my_dir or subdirs of my_dir.
>
> You can of course use -S to distribute the jobs to remote computers:
>
> ```
> inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir |\
>   parallel -S ..  -u echo
> ```
>
> If the files to be processed are in a tar file then unpacking one file and processing it immediately may be faster than first unpacking all files. Set up the dir processor as above and unpack into the dir.
>
> Using GNU parallel as dir processor has the same limitations as using GNU parallel as queue system/batch manager.

Answer (score 0):

For the infinite loop + `wait_for_IN_folder_changed`, [incrond](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) may help.

AFAIK, "parallel processes" and "multithreading" are very different things, and considering a given binary you can't modify or recompile, the only option left is parallel processing. 
There are several ways to implement this :

- the very basic : `tshark [options] &`
- some more advanced constructs with [xargs](https://man.cx/xargs)
- or dedicated tools such as [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

NB: maybe those are not even necessary when using "incrond" (not used it for a long time...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying out incron right now but i can't get it to run. I installed it and created the file /etc/incron.allow with root and my username. I created a rule `/media/sf_Java/receiver/pcap_IN/        IN_ALL_EVENTS   echo "$#" >> /media/sf_Java/receiver/log.txt` via `incrontab -e`. But if i add a file into that folder, nothing happens.